# why does a very simple phonegap app use mobile data plan?

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I've created a very simple mobile app with phonegap which doesn't do anything network related. All resources (images, css, etc) are local and I don't do any ajax calls to a remote server. But when I check the mobile data screen on my phone, I see that it has used some data. See screenshot bellow (4th app called "cherouvim phonegap test"). It says 308KB and that was in 5 hours.

[image]

Clicking on that gives me the following breakdown:

- foreground: 91.23KB
- background: 217KB

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I build with phonegap build and my config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "cherouvim.test"
    version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>cherouvim phonegap test</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <gap:platform name="android" />

</widget>
```

In the documentation it says:

```
<!-- If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires. -->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

Is this a hint that Phonegap actually does something network related behind the scenes?

**Edit:** In case it matters I'm using nexus 5 (android 4.4.4) and I've enabled the "developer mode" and the ART runtime.

Comment: Interesting! Have you tried to run your app in an emulator and use a network sniffer like Wireshark? Is it possible to get your apk to test?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used build, but I remember a debug button allowing use of weinre, maybe you have checked it?

Comment: can you try to build the same app with `cordova` and check whether it gives the same behavior? This way we can ascertain that it is only phonegap trying to gather some info (staistics). Or may be you could put a direct query on their (phonegag) community forum.

Comment: @NicolasR: Just did it and confirmed my finding that it's the debug build. Thanks.

Comment: That was (for my network studies point of view) a solution to confirm it, glad to help you (and to discover this thing)!

Comment: @NicolasR: Thanks. To be clear though, I initially found the problem by inspecting the `index.html` of the downloaded `apk`. If I had found the problem via your suggestion first (using wireshark) I would have asked you to post it as an answer so I would accept.

Comment: No problem, I was not looking at any reputation for my comment. And your way was easier to check, we should remember to use the apk format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the app in phonegap build with the "enable debugging" option set injects the following just before `</body>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#35fd7e24-189a-11e4-8c3c-e63707b18140"></script>
```

This is used for the weinre remote debugger of phonegap build.

Building without the "enable debugging" option doesn't inject this remote script. So, an app built for production use wouldn't actually use any mobile data as I initially thought it would.